# conversion of Int value String using user defaults having facing an error

Tags: swift, xcode, type-conversion, nsuserdefaults

```
UserInfoDefault.saveUserType(user: String(self.type))
```

I have to convert a type value that is `Int` and I have to convert it into `String` value to use it into the User defaults... But facing an issue :

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'String' with an argument list of type '(Int?)'

Comment: Please add proper code to help use understand more.

Comment: Can you share the code?

Answer (score 0):

Note the question mark, there is no init method for String that takes an optional Int. You need to unwrap it first.

```
let value = myOptionalInt ?? 0
let stringValue = String(value)
```

or use `if let` or `guard` depending on what suits your case the best